Book series about a boy who becomes a Space Emperor
I read a series of books back in the 80's about this family that was escaping from one of Jupiter's moons. They met up with some pirates, I believe the Daddy was killed then they arrived to safety. Eventually, the boy became the emperor of space. He got married and had kids. There were several books in the series

Piers Anthony's Bio of a Space Tyrant series.

The series revolves around the character Hope Hubris and his family,
and charts Hope's ascent from poor Hispanic refugee to Tyrant of
Jupiter, a single person heading the Executive, Judicial and
Legislative branches of the government.


The wording makes it sound as if the character stopped being Hispanic (along with a refugee and poor, obviously) when they became the Tyrant of Jupiter.

Advanced technology?

Probably. Also, it might normally be churlish to point out, for a setting hundreds of years in the future, that "Hope Hubris" is not a typical Hispanic nor even human name—not even Esperanza Hibris, which is equally silly—but apparently every part of every planet in this series has a one-to-one correspondence with parts of 20th-century Earth, so....
